# WatchKit Custom Interface for Recording Audio

Tags: watchkit, watchos-3

Is it possible to use our own Interface UI for WatchOS's recording instead of:
presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1628147-presentaudiorecordercontrollerwi

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this?